# Spider (Radar) chart for iOS

Tags: ios, charts

Where can I find good spider(radar) chart library for iOS? (as like the below)

[image]

I checked "Core Plot" and "iOSPlot" open source projects, but these are not supporting spider chart.

BR,
Wonil.

Comment: I made some changes from RP Radar Chart to fix color/data random mapping issue and to provide line touch detection. Please find this version from https://github.com/wonkim/RPRadarChart branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try RP Radar Chart from raspu on Github. Although the author claims it's unfinished it looks pretty solid. https://github.com/raspu/RPRadarChart

Comment: Hey, good to know you find it useful, I have several changes that needs to be pushed. Any request?

Comment: Hello Raspu, in fact, I made some changes by myself to use it from my project. :) You can find it from https://github.com/wonkim/RPRadarChart branch. Hope it can contribute little bit.

Comment: @Raspu: hi.. your chart works in an awesome way. however it plots only integers. Is it possible to plot values in points (eg 3.4 or 4.6)?? Also, if the name of the spoke is a little big, it is being cut. It is not displayed fully..

Comment: Hey @Shradha I'm no longer developing RPRadarChart, at the end I didn't had the time. But I think it was possible to plot floats, I am not sure what may be the problem. Maybe this library is more complete (and has a proper Pod): https://github.com/johnnywjy/JYRadarChart

Comment: @Wonil Sorry for no having the time to look in to your branch, it looks quite fine actually, if you want send me a merge request and I can merge it to master.

Comment: @Raspu I'll catch up this soon. Thanks! :)